# How to add iAd to Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad

I am working on an **universal app** and want to add an Ad Banner to it, the iAd is working fine in **iPhone**, But how to control that for **iPad**.

Because latest version of **iPad** supports **iAd** but in different size format and that gives error in my interface Builder when i targets for **iPad 3.2**.

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I haven't done that yet in my iPad apps, but here's how I would do it.

- First of all, I would mark the iAd framework as a weak/optional link. This would be the first step for compatibility with pre-iOS4. If you don't do that, the app may not even startup
- Secondly, I wouldn't add it in the nib file (if using one). I would rather add it programmatically to be ale to check if the iAd framework is available on device.
- Finally check if iAd is present. If it is, setup the ad, but if it isn't, just continue, or setup admob instead or something.

How to check that iAd is present? One of the simple ways is doing something like this

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView") != nil) {
    //iAd is present
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator